# zoom In and zoom out in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am a newbie in java so kindly correct my question if it has any ambiguity in it.

With my code zooming In and zooming Out are working. but the problem i am facing is line drawn on Buffered image exceeding the image when zoom_In is done. 
Assume a line is drawn on the edge of image, goes out of the image if zoom percentage is changed by slightly. say by .2 or .3 %.

Posting my code here for your better understating of the problem i am currently facing. Just have a Look.

```
public class PictureBox extends JPanel {

Graphics2D graphics2D;
static BufferedImage image;
private double zoom = 1.0;
private double percentage = .1;
int width = 0,height = 0;

public PictureBox(){
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    this.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("ComboBox.border"));
    this.repaint();     
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);    
    if(image == null){
        image = new BufferedImage(GlobalConstant.imageSize, GlobalConstant.imageSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        clear(); 
    }
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2D.scale(zoom, zoom);
    g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    repaint();
}


public final void putPixelForLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
    if(graphics2D != null){
    graphics2D.setColor(color);
    graphics2D.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    repaint();
    }
}

public void clear() {
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    repaint();
}

public void originalSize() {
    zoom = 1;
}

public void zoomIn() {
    zoom += percentage; 
    if(zoom > 1.66){
        zoom = 1.66;
    }   
        if(image != null){
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)zoom*image.getWidth(),(int)zoom*image.getHeight()));
        }

    revalidate();     
    repaint();
}

public void zoomOut() {
    zoom -= percentage;
    if(zoom < 0.2){
        zoom = 0.2;
    }
        if(image != null){
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)zoom*image.getWidth(),(int)zoom*image.getHeight()));
        }
    revalidate();     
    repaint();
}
```

}

Comment: Rather unclear what you're asking. However, try replacing occurances of `(int)zoom*somehing` with `(int)(Math.ceil(zoom*somehing)`, maybe it helps.

Comment: I am drawing shapes on BufferedImage at run time. When i zoom In, the drawn shapes goes out of images. Where i expect the image should get zoomed. But that's not happening. It behaves like drawn on other layer of image. I want to replicate something like Windows photo viewer.

Comment: The given code does not paint any shapes. Try to post a more complete example, to see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you follow the following procedure:

you have a loop somewhere like this

```
initiate the image
draw everything you want on the image: call pixelForLine() etc
while(true) {
  zoomIn();
  repaint();
  ... wait a bit
}
```

for testing zoom in - the equivalent for zooming out.

You should change your methods as follows:

a) calling repaint() inside paint() or paintComponent is an obvious flaw - remove repaint there.

b) changing the size of the jpanel has no meaning if you want to see the zoomingin/zoomout; if you change the size of the containing panel and the image nothing happens - both enlarge so nothing changes. (You have conflicting requirements here: it seems you attach the jpanel somewhere and you want to keep changing the size of the jpanel -  thats not good practice but I leave it up to you.) - so remove the setPreferredSize ... stuff. If you want to change the size somewhere nevertheless use setSize(); repaint(); (maybe validate() if necessary)

```
public void zoomIn() {
    zoom += percentage; 
    if(zoom > 1.66){
        zoom = 1.66;
    }   
}
```

c) remove repaint() from pixelForLine() - you draw the line on the image and repaint the image

d) (int)zoom*image.getWidth() should be (int)(zoom*image.getWidth())